# Optimal combination of two estimates

Tags: probability, probability-theory, parameter-estimation

I have a set of random variables, $X_1,\dots,X_N$. They are i.i.d. Gaussian with zero mean and $w$ variance. I observe $Y_1,\dots,Y_N$ where $Y_i=\sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij} X_j+N_i$ where all $a_{ij}$s are known and $N_i$ is Gaussian noise with zero mean and $\sigma^2$ variance.

Now I make a linear minimum mean squared error (LMMSE) estimate $\tilde{X}_{i^\prime1}$ of $X_{i^\prime}$ given $Y_1,\dots Y_{i^\prime}$. Then I make a similar estimate $\tilde{X}_{{i^\prime}2}$ of $X_{i^\prime}$ given $Y_{i^\prime},\dots Y_N$.

(a) Are these two estimates $\tilde{X}_{{i^\prime}1}$, $\tilde{X}_{{i^\prime}2}$ independent? My guess is not.

(b) What is the optimal combination of these two estimates $\tilde{X}_{{i^\prime}1}$ and $\tilde{X}_{{i^\prime}2}$?

Please explain these questions for me. Thanks a lot.

PS. The question [Optimally combining samples to estimate averages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9032/optimally-combining-samples-to-estimate-averages) is similar form but different as the estimates are independent.

Comment: Notation: You really shouldn't call your two estimates $X_1$ and $X_2$, since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are already used as two of the original observations!

Comment: Are those $a_j$ actually $a_{ij}$? Otherwise, $Y_i$ does not depend on $i$...

Comment: @Jens My interpretation is that $N_t$ should actually be $N_i$. That's the only way the $Y_i$'s differ.

Comment: @Jens corrected. thanks

Comment: @WillNelson Do you think this question is valid?

Comment: I think it's valid, though I haven't solved it. It's awfully confusing, though. You want to estimate $X_i$. Does that mean you want to estimate $X_i$ for one fixed $i$, or for each $i$? And I think it's very suspicious that you estimate $X_i$ given $Y_1,\ldots,Y_i$. The $i$'s in the previous sentence have absolutely nothing to do with one another. Why are they written the same? And then you re-estimate using $Y_i,\ldots, Y_n$. Again, why cut off at $i$? Can you make sure you're asking exactly the question you want to ask, then maybe I'll try to answer it.

Comment: @WillNelson I want to estimate one fixed $X_i$. I will mark it $i^\prime$ in the question. Then I want to estimate $X_{i^\prime}$ first using $Y_1,...,Y_{i^\prime}$ and then using $Y_{i^\prime},...,Y_N$. The number of $X_i$s and $Y_i$s are the same, i.e., $N$. In my problem the the observer $i^\prime$ is interested in estimating $X_{i^\prime}$ so there is a correspondense between the $i$s in $X_i$s and $i$s in $Y_i$s. Did I make it clear? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll outline the answer.

Really, this whole problem is just a variation on the computation of linear minimum mean square error estimators. Once you understand one, you understand them all!

Recall: Suppose $A$ is a random variable you want to estimate and $B_1,\ldots,B_n$ are random variables and $\mathbb{E}(A) = \mathbb{E}(B_i) = 0$ for all $i$. You want to form an estimator $\tilde{A} = \sum \alpha_i B_i$ of $A$ for some constants $\alpha\equiv(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ independent of $A$ and $B_i$. Observe
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}(\tilde{A} - A)^2 &=& \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_i \alpha_i B_i - A \right)^2 \\
 &=& \mathrm{Var}(A) + \sum_{i,j} \alpha_i \alpha_j \mathrm{Cov}(B_i,B_j) - 2\sum_i\mathrm{Cov}(A,B_i).
\end{eqnarray}
Differentiate to find the $\alpha$ yielding the minimum expected square error:
$$
\alpha = M^{-1} V
$$
where $M$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with $i,j$ entry $\mathrm{Cov}(B_i,B_j)$ and $V$ is the $n\times 1$ vector with $i$th entry $\mathrm{Cov}(A,B_i)$.

Okay. That was *really* general. It always works to find the linear estimator with minimum expected squared error (LMMSE or whatever you want to call it). No assumptions about independence or anything else. Only assumptions: $A,B_i$ are mean $0$ (can easily be extended), the $M$ matrix is non-singular (will always be true unless one of the $B_i$ is a linear combination of the others, i.e., is redundant), and the matrices $M$ and $V$ must be *known* (rarely true in the real world, often true in problem sets).

So in this problem, to compute $\tilde{X}_{i'1}$ and $\tilde{X}_{i'2}$, use the above method with with following calculations:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j) &=& w \sum_k a_{ik} a_{jk} + \sigma^2 \delta_{ij} \\
\mathrm{Cov}(X_{i'},Y_i) &=& w \alpha_{ii'}
\end{eqnarray}
Again, just carefully apply the above method. You're going to have to say something like, "The optimal $\alpha$ is $M^{-1} V$ where $M$ is the matrix ... and $V$ is the column vector ..." where the "..."s are given in terms of the $\mathrm{Cov}$ calculations given above. Not very insightful!

The only interesting thing here is that if one lets $V$ be the $n\times n$ covariance matrix with $i,j$ entry $\mathrm{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j)$, then
$$
V = w aa^T + \sigma^2 I_n
$$ 
where $a$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with $i,j$ entry $a_{ij}$.

To compute the optimal linear estimator given $\tilde{X}_{i1}$ and $\tilde{X}_{i2}$, you can use exactly the same method. However, the required calculations for $\mathrm{Cov}(\tilde{X}_{i1,2},\tilde{X}_{i1,2})$ and $\mathrm{Cov}(X_{i'},\tilde{X}_{i1,2})$ will depend on the optimal coefficients computed in the first part. And so it's possibly very messy. I my opinion, I would not be surprised if no big simplifications are possible. I don't know. Try it out. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks very clear. So is the result of, estimating $\tilde{X}_{{i^\prime}1}$ and $\tilde{X}_{{i^\prime}2}$ and then combining them to find $\tilde{X}_{{i^\prime}}$, same to the result if we directly estimated $\tilde{X}_{{i^\prime}}$ from all $Y_1,...,Y_N$?

Comment: I have not done the calculation, but I doubt that would be true. Perhaps it's true if you assume some structure on $a_{ij}$, but otherwise, I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks again. I am trying to develop a distributed algorithm for this problem for a research paper. Would you like to coauthor? I will only ask things to get clarification and verification, I will do all the writing, development, simulation.